# Jupyter notebook function, very slow all of a sudden, prun output says socket connect is taking 1 second per call?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, machine-learning, profiler

I was attempting to debug a function from a python file in jupyter notebook, I have run this exact function call many times before it usually takes about 20 minutes to run over thousands of observations.
This time however it is taking 18ish minutes for one call, I have not changed the function much if at all, it is simply slow now.
I have included the prun output for this function (truncated after 90 lines), annectdotely my hardware utilization also seems to be lower than in previous calls.

I do not have much experience wiht python profilers, glad to have any advice you can offer.

```
`    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1068 1074.943    1.007 1074.943    1.007 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
      534    0.517    0.001    0.518    0.001 {built-in method _socket.getaddrinfo}
     2705    0.071    0.000    0.071    0.000 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
     2848    0.063    0.000    0.088    0.000 url.py:210(_encode_invalid_chars)
      534    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
     1068    0.047    0.000    0.047    0.000 {function socket.close at 0x000001B86406E8B0}
      534    0.032    0.000 1075.608    2.014 connection.py:37(create_connection)
     1068    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 socket.py:220(__init__)
      219    0.031    0.000    0.040    0.000 basic.py:896(inner_predict)
      534/178    0.019    0.000 1075.855    6.044 connectionpool.py:522(urlopen)
    24078    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 geomath.py:63(polyval)
      890    0.011    0.000    0.098    0.000 url.py:330(parse_url)
      727    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 socket.py:480(send)
        59579    0.011    0.000    0.017    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        93286    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'bytes' objects}
      534    0.008    0.000    0.030    0.000 retry.py:504(increment)
       104008    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {built-in method builtins.ord}
      219    0.007    0.000    0.062    0.000 geodesic.py:701(_GenInverse)
      356    0.007    0.000    0.018    0.000 __init__.py:282(__init__)
      534    0.007    0.000 1075.616    2.014 connection.py:161(_new_conn)
      534    0.007    0.000    0.012    0.000 retry.py:304(new)
     3382    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'match' of 're.Pattern' objects}
      667    0.006    0.000    0.040    0.000 geodesic.py:624(_Lambda12)
      180    0.006    0.000    0.013    0.000 std.py:355(format_meter)
     1246    0.006    0.000    0.010    0.000 parse.py:437(urlsplit)
     3108    0.005    0.000    0.006    0.000 geodesic.py:122(_SinCosSeries)
     1068    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'setsockopt' of '_socket.socket' objects}
      886    0.005    0.000    0.025    0.000 geodesic.py:430(_Lengths)
     1602    0.005    0.000    0.012    0.000 _collections_abc.py:933(update)
      886    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 geodesic.py:205(_C1f)
    9120/8586    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
     1068    0.004    0.000    0.054    0.000 socket.py:497(close)
     4491    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method _abc._abc_instancecheck}
      534    0.004    0.000    0.529    0.001 socket.py:937(getaddrinfo)
      219    0.004    0.000    0.007    0.000 geodesic.py:367(_C4coeff)
      219    0.004    0.000    0.013    0.000 validation.py:494(check_array)
     1068    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 threading.py:351(notify)
     1068    0.004    0.000    0.009    0.000 connection.py:100(_set_socket_options)
      534    0.004    0.000    0.013    0.000 queue.py:122(put)
      534    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 retry.py:243(__init__)
      178    0.004    0.000 1075.965    6.045 adapters.py:395(send)
      219    0.004    0.000    0.078    0.000 sklearn.py:994(predict_proba)
      219    0.004    0.000    0.021    0.000 geodesic.py:275(__init__)
      534    0.004    0.000    0.020    0.000 connectionpool.py:996(_new_conn)
      219    0.004    0.000    0.006    0.000 geodesic.py:340(_C3coeff)
        1    0.004    0.004 1076.430 1076.430 2607826447.py:1(predict_ranking)
      657    0.004    0.000    0.025    0.000 series.py:1072(__setitem__)
      438    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
      534    0.003    0.000    0.009    0.000 connection.py:115(__init__)
     1068    0.003    0.000    0.015    0.000 parse.py:372(urlparse)
      668    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 geodesic.py:255(_C2f)
      534    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 client.py:843(__init__)
      219    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 basic.py:730(__init__)
     2439    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 geomath.py:34(norm)
     1250    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 threading.py:256(__enter__)
     8932    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 utils.py:330(<genexpr>)
      534    0.003    0.000 1075.620    2.014 connectionpool.py:1032(_validate_conn)
     3026    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 parse.py:114(_coerce_args)
      890    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 url.py:244(_remove_path_dot_segments)
     1068    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 idna.py:147(encode)
      178    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 poolmanager.py:79(_default_key_normalizer)
     1232/616    0.003    0.000    0.015    0.000 point.py:154(__new__)
     2136    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 enum.py:358(__call__)
      534    0.003    0.000 1075.627    2.014 connectionpool.py:361(_make_request)
     1437    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
     1068    0.003    0.000    0.050    0.000 socket.py:493(_real_close)
      657    0.003    0.000    0.014    0.000 series.py:1145(_set_with_engine)
     1246    0.003    0.000    0.016    0.000 sessions.py:50(merge_setting)
     1424    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'search' of 're.Pattern' objects}
     1068    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'settimeout' of '_socket.socket' objects}
      667    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 geodesic.py:405(_C3f)
      534    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 retry.py:488(is_exhausted)
    17383/17015    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
     1246    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 timeout.py:102(__init__)
     2136    0.003    0.000    0.007    0.000 socket.py:99(_intenum_converter)
     1246    0.003    0.000    0.008    0.000 utils.py:322(to_key_val_list)
      657    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 base.py:172(setitem_inplace)
      356    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 __init__.py:1514(findCaller)
      356    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 ntpath.py:180(split)
     3738    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 timeout.py:119(_validate_timeout)
      356    0.002    0.000    0.010    0.000 parse.py:912(urlencode)
     1602    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 parse.py:890(quote_from_bytes)
      219    0.002    0.000    0.005    0.000 basic.py:512(c_float_array)
      178    0.002    0.000    0.128    0.001 std.py:1212(update)
     5340    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 six.py:1015(ensure_text)
      356    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 retry.py:354(get_backoff_time)
      178    0.002    0.000 1076.056    6.045 sessions.py:457(request)
     3738    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 structures.py:48(__setitem__)
      219    0.002    0.000 1076.086    4.914 1170078126.py:1(func)`
```

This function is called multiple times, by another function which itself is called hundreds of times, like I said this ran fine before.
Tried restarting my computer,
updating drivers,
checking for anaconda conflicts.

prun is on the single function call only.

Comment: It looks like you are fetching a URL.  The most likely answer is that the server is clogged up, or is having network difficulties.